# Android: Orientation changes- Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

I am trying to get my app up and  running but I am facing with the problem so  I am trying to save screen state when Android orientation changes but the app is always keeping  crashing all the time and I am getting the following error above otherwise the app is working fine. I think that the last 2 methodes (onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState) are causing the problem.

I appreciate any help.

```js
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3924)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:161)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at com.planetplace.GPSAPlanetActivity.onRestoreInstanceState(GPSAPlanetActivity.java:212)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:949)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1156)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
03-30 15:14:40.199: E/AndroidRuntime(18902):  ... 12 more
```

GPSAPlanetActivity:

```js
package com.planetplace;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.plant.abc.Plant;

public class GPSAPlanetActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

 private static final String PLANT2 = "PLANT";
 private static final String LONGITUDE2 = "Longitude";
 private static final String LATITUDE2 = "Latitude";
 EditText description;
 TextView txtSelectedPlant;
 public final static int CAREA_RESULT = 5;
 public Bitmap plantImage;
 private ImageView imgPlant;
 private LocationManager LocationManager;
 private Plant plant;
 private double latitude;
 private double longitude;
 private TextView lblLatitudeValue;
 private TextView lblLongitudevalue;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps_plants);
  description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDescription);
  txtSelectedPlant = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedPlant);

  // get a references to the image view that will display a plant photot.
  imgPlant = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPlant);

  // get the LocationManager as a system service. Save it into a field
  LocationManager = (android.location.LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

  lblLatitudeValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLatt);
  lblLongitudevalue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLong);

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
  // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
  // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
  int id = item.getItemId();
  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
   return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

 public void searchClicked(View v) {
  Intent searchIntent = new Intent(this, AdvancedSearchActivity.class);

  startActivityForResult(searchIntent,
    AdvancedSearchActivity.PLANT_RESULTS);

 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

   if (requestCode == AdvancedSearchActivity.PLANT_RESULTS) {
    // change the label of the text view to be the plant that was
    // passed
    // in

    // store the plant as an attribute
    Plant plant = (Plant) data
      .getSerializableExtra(PlantResultActivity.PLANT_RESULT);

    // set this plant in the TextView on the UI
    txtSelectedPlant.setText(plant.toString());
   } else if (requestCode == CAREA_RESULT) {
    // we are here because we received result from the camera
    plantImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

    imgPlant.setImageBitmap(plantImage);
   }
  }
 }

 public void onTakePhotoClicked(View v) {
  // use an implicit intent to invoke the camera
  Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

  // start this intent, and antipcipate a result.
  startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAREA_RESULT);

 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onResume();
  requestLocation();
 }

 private void requestLocation() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if (LocationManager != null) {
   // the variable locationManger has an object assigned to it if we
   // have gotten inside this
   // if test. we want to do a null check like this first, because we
   // want to avoid a NullPointerException.

   // request location update
   LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
     LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 0, this);

  }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPause();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStart() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onStart();
 }

 // this method will be invoked when the GPS service informs us that us that
 // our Location has changed.
 // Anything that we want to do that should be updated when the GPS position
 // of our phone as moved
 // we must do in this method
 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  latitude = location.getLatitude();
  longitude = location.getLongitude();

  updateUIForLocation();

 }

 private void updateUIForLocation() {
  // update our user interface.
  lblLatitudeValue.setText("" + latitude);
  lblLongitudevalue.setText("" + longitude);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
 //This method is called right before we change orientation, so that we can preserve values when the screen is redrawn
 @Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  outState.putDouble(LATITUDE2, latitude);
  outState.putDouble(LONGITUDE2, longitude);
  outState.putSerializable(PLANT2, plant);
  

 }
 /**
  * Dispaly values in the UI that were saved right before orientation changed.
  */
 @Override
 protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  //repopulate values from the bundle we created in onSaveInstanceState method.
  latitude  = savedInstanceState.getDouble(LATITUDE2);
  longitude  = savedInstanceState.getDouble(LONGITUDE2);
  updateUIForLocation();
  plant = (Plant) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(PLANT2);
  txtSelectedPlant.setText(plant.toString());
 }

}
```

Plant class:

```js
package com.plant.abc;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Plant implements Serializable {

 private String genus;
 private String species;
 private String cultivar;
 private String common;
 private int id;
 private int guid;

 public String getGenus() {
  return genus;
 }

 public void setGenus(String genus) {
  this.genus = genus;
 }

 public String getSpecies() {
  return species;
 }

 public void setSpecies(String species) {
  this.species = species;
 }

 public String getCultivar() {
  return cultivar;
 }

 public void setCultivar(String cultivar) {
  this.cultivar = cultivar;
 }

 public String getCommon() {
  return common;
 }

 public void setCommon(String common) {
  this.common = common;
 }

 public int getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public int getGuid() {
  return guid;
 }

 public void setGuid(int guid) {
  this.guid = guid;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return genus + " " + species + " " + common;
 }

}
```

XML file:

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.plantplaces.GPSAPlanetActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="GPS A Planet" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Description of the Plant" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bntSearchPlant"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bntSearchPlant"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="Lattitude" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLatt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/etDescription"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Longitude" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvLatt"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="Selected Plant" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSelectedPlant"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvLong"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvLong"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCaptureImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bntSearchPlant"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:onClick="onTakePhotoClicked"
        android:text="Take Photo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bntSearchPlant"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etDescription"
        android:onClick="searchClicked"
        android:text="select a Planet" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPlant"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCaptureImage"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you point out the line of error.

Comment: There is no error in eclipse the crashing is just occuring if I try to turn the S4 device.

Comment: no error in log cat? when the application is run by means of AVD?

Comment: `GPSAPlanetActivity.onRestoreInstanceState(GPSAPlanetActivity.java:212)`

Comment: I think you might be having different layouts file for different orientation but you will be using different 'id' for view inside it.Please post your xml code

Comment: Please post which line of your `onRestoreInstanceState()` method is at line number 212. This is where the `NullPointerException` is occurring.

Comment: @Kesh1234 I have already posted the error in the logcat file that is the error, I am getting when the app crashes. Karthika PB I added my xml file

Comment: @bwegs this line "txtSelectedPlant.setText(plant.toString());" the last line in the class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @MrAsker If my solution helped solve your problem could you mark it as the correct answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `plant` is null when `onRestoreInstanceState()` is called because `plant` is initialized in your `onActivityResult()` method (not in your `onCreate()` method). Change your code to check to see if plant is null before trying to retrieve it and set the text of your `EditText`:

```
plant = (Plant) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(PLANT2);

if(plant != null)  // plant may have been null when it was saved in onSaveInstanceState
    txtSelectedPlant.setText(plant.toString());
```

Comment: this is line 211. Should I change line 211"plant = (Plant) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(PLANT2);" to "Plant plant = (Plant) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(PLANT2);"  what should I do with this line "txtSelectedPlant.setText(plant.toString())"

Comment: Yes, my mistake, try changing line 211 to the line I posted in my answer. Leave line 212 as it is.

Comment: @MrAsker Can you post the code of your `plant` class?

Comment: @MrAsker disregard my last comment and see my updated answer. You're most likely changing the orientation while `plant` is `null`. Just check for this instead before trying to set your `EditText` with its contents.

Comment: I  added the if condition I am getting something back on "txtSelectedPlant" as before but if I change the orientation the value of "txtSelectedPlant" disappeares. There is no crashing because of the if condition. I added the plant class too.

Comment: @MrAsker Ok if the problem you're having is losing the value inside of `txtSelectedPlant` then I'd suggest just saving and restoring that value directly in the `instanceState` with `outState.putString("PLANT_TEXT", txtSelectedPlant.getText().toString());` in `onSaveInstanceState()` and `txtSelectedPlant.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("PLANT_TEXT"));` in `onRestoreInstanceState()`